# Duplicating many files with some modifications to the content

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to automate the problem of making small changes to a large number of files

This is for my own personal web project, not homework, not employer related. I am working on a Linux computer. I have tried some shell scripts involving sed and awk  but I do not know enough to get it done.

I have a directory with about 200 files. Each file contains a single line of the form

```
   <a href="A.php">A</a> -> <a href="pageA.php">Page A</a> ->  
    Title A (tag 1)
```

where the actual value of A is different for every file, but all the rest of the code is identical in each file.
I would like to make a copy of each file (with same filename, in a different directory) with the line replaced by

```
    <a href="A.php">A</a> -> <a href="pageA.php">Page A</a> -> 
    <a href="A1.php"> Title A</a> ->  (tag 2)
```

where the value of A1 varies with each file and should consist of the content of another file with identical filename (in a different directory)

Comment: Can you provide am example (name, content) for the 'content of another file'

Comment: @dash-o yes, it will be just a filename, in fact the same filename as the file that is being duplicated

Comment: In fact the value of A1 is just the filename of the file being duplicated. So if the file being duplicated is named Altitude, then A1 is just Altitude